# mayavi points3d plot animation won't update the next frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, animation, numpy, mayavi

I am writing a code that visualization of four glyphs moving through space. At the moment the the mayavi window shows the the initial positions, but wont update to the next position.

```
    #Library decleration 
import numpy as np
from mayavi.mlab import *

....

#Inputting the intital positions into the storage vector
storage_position[0].append(v_1.theta)
storage_position[1].append(v_1.phi)
#Calculating the rest of the positions using the symmetry given
storage_position = Sym(storage_position)

#Plotting the intitial positions 

x_coord = x_trans( storage_position)
y_coord = y_trans(storage_position)
z_coord = z_trans( storage_position)


plt = points3d(x_coord, y_coord, z_coord)

msplt = plt.mlab_source
@mlab.animate(delay=100)
def anim(storage_position, storage_vort, no_vort ,x_coord, y_coord, z_coord):
    f = mlab.gcf()
    while True:
    #for i in range(10):      
        #Working out the hamiltonian
        #Hami(storage_position, storage_vort, 1 - 1, no_vort-1)

        transfer_vector = method(storage_position, storage_vort, 1 - 1, no_vort-1)
        storage_position[0].append(transfer_vector[0])
        storage_position[1].append(transfer_vector[1])
        storage_position = Sym(storage_position)


        x_coord = x_trans( storage_position)
        y_coord = y_trans(storage_position)
        z_coord = z_trans( storage_position)

        msplt.set(x_coord = x_coord, y_coord = y_coord, z_coord = z_coord)

        yield


anim(storage_position, storage_vort, no_vort - 1,x_coord, y_coord, z_coord)
mlab.show()
```

x_coord etc are numpy vectors that stores the x coordinates for the four glyphs. x_trans etc are functions that update each vector with the new coordinates for each step of the animation.

Comment: Can you give a complete executable example?  The code above doesn't define `x_trans`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying replacing this line:

```
msplt.set(x_coord = x_coord, y_coord = y_coord, z_coord = z_coord)
```

with this:

```
msplt.set(x=x_coord, y=y_coord, z=z_coord)
```

The point set data source (which should be an object of type `MGlyphSource`) knows about `x`, `y` and `z`, but `x_coord`, `y_coord` and `z_coord` aren't supported as keyword arguments.

Here's a complete working example to get you started:

```
from mayavi import mlab
from numpy import array, cos, sin, cos

x_coord = array([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -1.0])
y_coord = array([1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0])
z_coord = array([0.2, -0.2, 0.2, -0.2])

plt = mlab.points3d(x_coord, y_coord, z_coord)

msplt = plt.mlab_source
@mlab.animate(delay=100)
def anim():
    angle = 0.0
    while True:
        x_coord = array([sin(angle), cos(angle), -sin(angle), -cos(angle)])
        y_coord = array([cos(angle), -sin(angle), -cos(angle), sin(angle)])
        msplt.set(x=x_coord, y=y_coord)
        yield
        angle += 0.1

anim()
mlab.show()
```

Note that when you run this, you'll probably see a lot of warnings printed to the console.  Ignore them: they're harmless and a [known issue](https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/issues/3).